# display using foreach, but adjust space between row and columns

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying same image for `24 times with 3 * 8 matrix` in `A4 size` (using `foreach`).

The problem is, i need to add space manually with every row and column. but it should not break the page. The `3 * 8` matrix should place in same page.

My `css` is

```
foreach method
    <div id="qr" style="display: inline-block; width:6.9cm; height:4cm;" >
       (image)
    </div>
end foreach
```

i'm asking how increase the space between two rows without page break.

IF i add width from 6.9 to 7.2 to increase, the eigth row goto second page, while printing

Answer (score 0):

When using display:inline-block, or display:inline css properties, remove white spaces (space/tab between the tags).

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a margin to the top/bottom of the divs. This will put space between them and the next elements below them.

```
margin: 10px 0px; // This will add 10px of space above AND below the div.

margin-bottom: 10px; // This way you can specifically target a side of the "box".
```